# PHP Call-time pass-by-reference unavoidable?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Given the following interface:

```
interface ISoapInterface {
  public static function registerSoapTypes( &$wsdl );
  public static function registerSoapOperations( &$server );
}
```

And the following code:

```
$soapProvider = array( "FilePool", "UserList" );
foreach( $soapProvider as $provider ) {
  call_user_func( array( $provider, "registerSoapTypes" ), &$server->wsdl );
  call_user_func( array( $provider, "registerSoapOperations" ), &$server );
}
```

`FilePool` and `UserList` both implement `ISoapInterface`.

PHP will complain about the two calls inside the foreach stating:

> Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated

So I looked that message up, and [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) seems quite clear on how to resolve this. Removing the ampersand from the actual call.
So I changed my code to look like this:

```
$soapProvider = array( "FilePool", "UserList" );
foreach( $soapProvider as $provider ) {
  call_user_func( array( $provider, "registerSoapTypes" ), $server->wsdl );
  call_user_func( array( $provider, "registerSoapOperations" ), $server );
}
```

Now PHP complains

> Parameter 1 to FilePool::registerSoapTypes expected to be reference, value given
>   Parameter 1 to FilePool::registerSoapOperations expected to be reference, value given

In addition to that, the functionality is now broken. So this obviously can't be the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

> Note that the parameters for call_user_func() are not passed by reference.

To invoke static methods you can use `Class::method()` syntax, supplying a variable for the `Class` and/or `method` parts:

```
$soapProvider = array( "FilePool", "UserList" );
foreach( $soapProvider as $provider ) {
  $provider::registerSoapTypes($server->wsdl);
  $provider::registerSoapOperations($server);
}
```

Comment: If I use $provider->registerSoapTypes, I get Call to member function registerSoapTypes on a non-object. The methods are static. That's what initially lead me to call_user_func, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @gencha I missed the `static`; will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

While `call_user_func` does not pass parameters by reference, [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) can.

```
$callback = array($provider, 'blahblahblah');
call_user_func_array($callback, array( &$server ));
```

The only real difference is that it expects an array of parameters instead of a list of parameters like `call_user_func` (similar to the difference between [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and [`vsprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php))...

Comment: This actually works perfectly, I'm just still wondering if I'm missing something about meagar's solutions. Thanks

Comment: Well, @meagar's solution is fine.  It's just calling the method directly rather than invoking a function to do it.  It's like doing `$object->method()`, but for static methods `class::method()` or `$className::method()` where `$className` holds a string name of the class (as in your original code).  Both solutions work fine.  @meagar's is a little faster and more efficient, but mine is more flexible (the `$callback` can be anything, and the number of arguments can be variable).  Both are valid...